# How to open image in client via SSH

Tags: ssh

I am using client as a display laptop. I want to control the window via server SSH. 
however, when I run `wmctrl -n 1` it always said Cannot find display.

I wish to use SSH to have a control of client's display.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try `export DISPLAY=:0 ; wmctrl -n 1`.

You should also do `ssh -X user@pc` (Thanks @green frog).

Comment: I did. however it dones't work.
The terminal has nothing to return. It seems work but when I use [code]wmctrl -l [/code]to check there is no new display. Also I tried [code]wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -t 1; wmctrl -s 1[\code]
but still noting changed

Comment: Did you do an `ssh -X [...]` ? to allow the ssh export display ?

Comment: Sadly it can't.
However when I put 
`env DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHOURITY=~/.Xauthority [......]` it works